# Insurance, beneficiary

Tags: united-states

I need help or insight about this matter. My grandfather recently died. He's a retired US military, dual citizen US and in the Philippines. But, he lived in the Philippines through out his life. He have both family in the US and here in the Philippines.
My Dad is the only legal son under his name but my Dad died before him. Is there any insurance, benefits or something that we can claim? If yes, what are the documents needed or action to take?

Comment: Sorry about your grandfather. And sorry that your question got closed prematurely. That being said, there is no way for us to know what will, insurance, or retirement plan he had. The retirement plan might only cover your grandfather's spouse and perhaps any dependent children, though.

Comment: This isn't a request for legal advice, so it shouldn't have been closed as such, but it isn't particularly about _law,_ either.  You might find a more receptive audience for this question at [Money.SE].

Comment: @IñakiViggers OP obviously doesn't know what retirement plan to look for, either.  I would interpret the question as "what death benefits are US military veterans automatically entitled to, if any?"

Comment: I'm not sufficiently aware of US / Philippine estate laws to provide a full answer, but I would start by reaching out to customer service departments of every organization your grandfather was involved in, including the US military and any bank(s) he had accounts with. Brace yourself for a long process of confirming your identity and back and forth to speak with someone sufficiently senior to help you. A lawyer might perhaps be able to help you, especially if there was a will registered in the court system, however you might want to defer that expense until you can't progress further yourself.